# Language for computationaly intense serverside

Tags: web-applications, application-structure

I am developing my first web application and need help with choosing right frameworks. As of now I have experience with vanilla JS and css, but no frameworks - just to give a sense of what I might not know.

Firstly, to describe what I am building. Its is a server based app, which gets some basic location data from the client and with data from JAXA digital world topography map API generates the horizon, as seen from client's location, using roughly 20k recursion algorithms of order 10k elements each, basic arithmetic and array comparisons of 20k elements. The horizon is displayed to the client as a one page application, which is essentially a 3D environment in the shape of sphere (or at least as a cylindrical projection - if 2D rendering is significantly easier to implement and has a great effect on performance). A good analogy for how it would look are these astronomy apps, which tell you exactly where each star is on the sky.

As I have no experience with web frameworks and what works best for such use case (I do not want to take another student debt to run the server) I am seeking help here. To be honest I am not a  huge fan of React and Javascript and would want to evade it at least on the back end. I was thinking of using Svelte for front end and Django for back end. Is this a viable option, or should I switch to compiled language for back end like Go, Rust or Elixir with Phoenix framework?
The fact is that I would really like something in Python on back end, because I am the most familiar with it. I don't know any of previously listed compiled languages, but I am willing to learn something new.
Speaking of learning something new, I thought learning Svelte to start web dev would be a good choice, because I'd still like to have libraries at hand to use these fancy designer stuff like blurred UI elements and animations (no I do not want to spend half a day trying to figure out why my text is not centered) - all though I probably should do some custom UI just for fun. To get back to the point lack of libraries for other alternatives like Qwik or Solid is kind of keeping me from trying to start with them (or else please correct me if I am wrong and there are such libraries with fancy blurred UI elements for Solid...)

Id love your feedback on how to structure such application and thanks for everyone's time!